# SPARQL recursive queries task

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I found a SPARQL task that I can't finish. I am a beginner at SPARQL so I would be glad for some help. The endpoint is https://query.wikidata.org/.

> - Write a SELECT query:
>
>   - Find all ingredients (parts, wdt:P527) of pad thai, recursively. So, also include parts of parts and parts of parts of parts, etc.
>   - Find all things that have at least one ingredient in common with the pad thai. Here also make this recursive, so include parts of parts, etc.
>   - Include only things that are a part of (wdt:P361) a European cuisine. There are many European cuisines – look recursively for subclasses (wdt:P279) of the “European cuisine” item.
> - In the results include:
>
>   - The URI of the food.
>   - The food’s English label with its description together in format like “label – description”. If there is no description for the food, output only the label.
>   - English labels of all parts that this food has in common with pad thai, with “; “ as the separator between values.
>   - English labels of all European cuisines that this food belongs to, with “; “ as the separator.

I found out that I can search title and combine it with description thanks to:

```
WHERE 
{  
  wd:Q730298 wdt:P527* ?ingredient .
  wd:Q579316 ^wdt:P279* ?europeanCuisines.
  ?food wdt:P527+ ?ingredient;
              wdt:P361 ?europeanCuisines.
```

but it is black magic to me how to finish the rest.

Comment: `select ?food (IF(BOUND(?foodDescription), CONCAT(?foodLabel, " - ", ?foodDescription), ?foodLabel) as ?text)
(group_concat(distinct ?ingredientLabel; separator="; ") AS ?ingredients)
(group_concat(distinct ?europeanCuisinesLabel; separator="; ") AS ?cuisines) {
select ?food ?foodLabel ?foodDescription ?ingredientLabel ?europeanCuisinesLabel {
wd:Q730298 wdt:P527* ?ingredient .
wd:Q579316 ^wdt:P279* ?europeanCuisines.
?food wdt:P527+ ?ingredient;
wdt:P361 ?europeanCuisines.
SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}} group by ?food ?foodLabel ?foodDescription`

Comment: @UninformedUser why do you write your answers in the comments?